# Where are man pages stored in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, man

I hope my question isn't too trivial, but I've never actually needed to know this before.

In which directory can I find the files of the man pages, i.e. the read-only text file opened when you type `man foo`? I assume different distros may keep them in slightly different places, so if it makes any difference I run Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Use **`manpath`** to see the directories used by your system, and **`man --where --all foo`** to find a specific manual page of *foo*.

The standard location is **`/usr/share/man`** according to [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRSHAREMANMANUALPAGES), and `/usr/man` is usually a symlink to that directory.

Other locations can be defined in `/etc/manpath.config` or `/etc/man_db.conf` (exact location varies). For example, /usr/local/share/man is almost always included.

In addition, *man* tries to find manual pages for every directory specified in $PATH – for example, if you added /opt/plan9/bin to $PATH, *man* will automatically search /opt/plan9/man and /opt/plan9/bin/man.

If the `$MANPATH` environment variable is set, however, it will override *all* other sources.

Comment: I know this question is for Ubuntu, but if anybody from macOS is here, the equivalent is `man -w -a foo`.  It appears Apple's `man` does not have the longer `--where` and `--all` options

Answer (score 8):

In the files that end with .gz when using `whereis`:

```
whereis man
```

output:

```
man: /usr/bin/man /usr/bin/X11/man /usr/local/man /usr/share/man /usr/share/man/man1/man.1.gz /usr/share/man/man7/man.7.gz
```

Example with grep:

```
whereis grep
```

output:

```
grep: /bin/grep /usr/share/man/man1/grep.1.gz
```

**minor update on how to read these gz files:**

```
info /usr/share/man/man1/grep.info.gz
zcat /usr/share/man/man1/grep.1.gz | less
```

or if it is in the name.number.gz format:

```
zcat /usr/share/man/man1/grep.1.gz | less
# or more readable
man /usr/share/man/man1/grep.1.gz
```

Comment: `whereis` tells you the location of a program, so doing `whereis man` will tell you where the `man` executable is stored, but not the man pages themselves.

Comment: @jff is incorrect here. From the manual page for whereis: 'whereis - locate the binary, source, and manual page files for a command'. Using `whereis -m grep` will restrict output just to the location of the manual page files.

Answer (score 4):

They should be under `/usr/share/man`.